# Capturar valor $.getJson esta vindo undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, append

Estou tentando montar um tabela a partir de um **JSON** que recebo de uma página **php**, entretanto quando faço o *append* o valor capturado aparece como *undefined*.

```js
$.getJSON("getEventoCategoria.php", {ID_EVT_Evento: ID},function (data) {
                var tabledata = "";
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data[0].DSC_Nome);
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    console.log(item.DSC_Nome);
                    console.log(item.VLR_Inscricao);
                    
                    $('#conteudoTabelaCategoria')
                            .append(
                                    "<tr>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.DSC_Nome + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.VLR_Inscricao + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.DT_Inicio_Valor + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.DT_Fim_Valor + "</td>" +
                                    "</tr>"
                                    );
                });
            });
```

no arquivo php:

```html
<?php

$ID_EVT_Evento = $_REQUEST['ID_EVT_Evento'];
require_once './actions/aEvt_Evento_Categoria.php';

$EventoCategoria = new aEvt_Evento_Categoria();

$arr[] = $EventoCategoria->selectCategoriasDoEvento($ID_EVT_Evento);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

quando faço um get direto pela url ele me exibe o seguinte JSON:

```html
[[{"ID_Evento_Categoria":"528c234df006558ae470fa0ccabe7892","DSC_Nome":"Categoria 01","VLR_Inscricao":"100.00","DT_Inicio_Valor":"2015-01-01","DT_Fim_Valor":"2015-12-31","ID_EVT_Evento":"528c234df006558ae470fa0ccabe7892"}]]
```

Coloquei uns log's para debug.
Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Comment: O que retorna o `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: 0: Array[1]
  0: Object
   DSC_Nome: "Categoria 01"
   DT_Fim_Valor: "2015-12-31"
   DT_Inicio_Valor: "2015-01-01"
   ID_EVT_Evento: "528c234df006558ae470fa0ccabe7892"
   ID_Evento_Categoria: "528c234df006558ae470fa0ccabe7892"
   VLR_Inscricao: "100.00"

Comment: no php aparece assim:

Comment: [[{"ID_Evento_Categoria":"528c234df006558ae470fa0ccabe7892","DSC_Nome":"Categoria 01","VLR_Inscricao":"100.00","DT_Inicio_Valor":"2015-01-01","DT_Fim_Valor":"2015-12-31","ID_EVT_Evento":"528c234df006558ae470fa0ccabe7892"}]]

Comment: Cole na questão o que o seu arquivo `getEventoCategoria.php` faz !!!

Comment: coloquei na questão.

Comment: nessa linha $arr[] = $EventoCategoria->selectCategoriasDoEvento($ID_EVT_Evento); coloque some $arr = $EventoCategoria->selectCategoriasDoEvento($ID_EVT_Evento); porque está criando array do array na minha visão! que vai funcionar !!!

Comment: ALELUIA............

Comment: Era isso mesmo....

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: eu acho melhor tu excluir essa questão!

Answer (score 2):

Resolvido.
Apenas removi os "[]" na variável "arr" no arquivo php.